# Tensorflow_hub not importing even after installing

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow

I have installed TensorFlow_hub from conda by doing this:
`conda install -c conda-forge tensorflow-hub`

However, when I try to import tensorflow_hub anywhere, I get this error;

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
/tmp/ipykernel_14843/980229998.py in <module>
      1 import tensorflow as tf
----> 2 import tensorflow_hub as hub

~/anaconda3/envs/PoseEstimation/lib/python3.9/site-packages/tensorflow_hub/__init__.py in <module>
     86 
     87 
---> 88 from tensorflow_hub.estimator import LatestModuleExporter
     89 from tensorflow_hub.estimator import register_module_for_export
     90 from tensorflow_hub.feature_column import image_embedding_column

~/anaconda3/envs/PoseEstimation/lib/python3.9/site-packages/tensorflow_hub/estimator.py in <module>
     60 
     61 
---> 62 class LatestModuleExporter(tf.compat.v1.estimator.Exporter):
     63   """Regularly exports registered modules into timestamped directories.
     64 

~/anaconda3/envs/PoseEstimation/lib/python3.9/site-packages/tensorflow/python/util/lazy_loader.py in __getattr__(self, item)
     60 
     61   def __getattr__(self, item):
---> 62     module = self._load()
     63     return getattr(module, item)
     64 

~/anaconda3/envs/PoseEstimation/lib/python3.9/site-packages/tensorflow/python/util/lazy_loader.py in _load(self)
     43     """Load the module and insert it into the parent's globals."""
     44     # Import the target module and insert it into the parent's namespace
---> 45     module = importlib.import_module(self.__name__)
     46     self._parent_module_globals[self._local_name] = module
     47 

~/anaconda3/envs/PoseEstimation/lib/python3.9/importlib/__init__.py in import_module(name, package)
    125                 break
    126             level += 1
--> 127     return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
    128 
    129 

~/anaconda3/envs/PoseEstimation/lib/python3.9/site-packages/tensorflow_estimator/python/estimator/api/__init__.py in <module>
      8 import sys as _sys
      9 
---> 10 from tensorflow_estimator.python.estimator.api._v1 import estimator
     11 
     12 del _print_function

~/anaconda3/envs/PoseEstimation/lib/python3.9/site-packages/tensorflow_estimator/python/estimator/api/_v1/estimator/__init__.py in <module>
      8 import sys as _sys
      9 
---> 10 from tensorflow_estimator.python.estimator.api._v1.estimator import experimental
     11 from tensorflow_estimator.python.estimator.api._v1.estimator import export
     12 from tensorflow_estimator.python.estimator.api._v1.estimator import inputs

~/anaconda3/envs/PoseEstimation/lib/python3.9/site-packages/tensorflow_estimator/__init__.py in <module>
      8 import sys as _sys
      9 
---> 10 from tensorflow_estimator._api.v1 import estimator
     11 
     12 del _print_function

~/anaconda3/envs/PoseEstimation/lib/python3.9/site-packages/tensorflow_estimator/_api/v1/estimator/__init__.py in <module>
     11 from tensorflow_estimator._api.v1.estimator import export
     12 from tensorflow_estimator._api.v1.estimator import inputs
---> 13 from tensorflow_estimator._api.v1.estimator import tpu
     14 from tensorflow_estimator.python.estimator.canned.baseline import BaselineClassifier
     15 from tensorflow_estimator.python.estimator.canned.baseline import BaselineEstimator

~/anaconda3/envs/PoseEstimation/lib/python3.9/site-packages/tensorflow_estimator/_api/v1/estimator/tpu/__init__.py in <module>
     12 from tensorflow_estimator.python.estimator.tpu.tpu_config import RunConfig
     13 from tensorflow_estimator.python.estimator.tpu.tpu_config import TPUConfig
---> 14 from tensorflow_estimator.python.estimator.tpu.tpu_estimator import TPUEstimator
     15 from tensorflow_estimator.python.estimator.tpu.tpu_estimator import TPUEstimatorSpec
     16 

~/anaconda3/envs/PoseEstimation/lib/python3.9/site-packages/tensorflow_estimator/python/estimator/tpu/tpu_estimator.py in <module>
    106 
    107 # Track the adoption of TPUEstimator
--> 108 _tpu_estimator_gauge = tf.compat.v2.__internal__.monitoring.BoolGauge(
    109     '/tensorflow/api/tpu_estimator',
    110     'Whether the program uses tpu estimator or not.')

AttributeError: module 'tensorflow._api.v2.compat.v2.__internal__' has no attribute 'monitoring'
```

My TensorFlow versions as per conda list in the current environment are as follows:

tensorflow                2.4.1
tensorflow-base           2.4.1
tensorflow-estimator      2.6.0
tensorflow-gpu            2.4.1
tensorflow-hub            0.12.0

What do I do to import tfhub without any error?

Thank You

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The environment mentioned below are worked for me

> tensorflow-2.4.1
> tensorflow-estimator-2.4.0
> tensorflow-gpu-2.4.1
> tensorflow-hub-0.12.0

Downgarde tensorflow-estimator to 2.4.0